# Word for mildly and politely telling someone what to do

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word or phrase somewhere between telling and asking  someone to do something.
Example 1: xyz clean up your workspace when done
Example 2: I needed to xyz the programmer to modify the program.

Comment: "Would you mind (doing something)?"

Comment: "Would you please (request)?"

Comment: I would appreciate (it) if you could (request) - The most polite version.

Comment: *Request.*  The more polite and less imperative form of *ask*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

English is absolutely full of alternatives for polite demands! English seems to be to be one of the most understated languages whereby a polite request is in fact a demand in disguise.

**Example 1**

- I would really appreciate your cleaning your workspace
- I would be grateful if you could clean your workspace when you are finished
- We should all clean our workspaces at the end of the day
- It is good practice to clean your workspace when complete
- It would please me greatly if you could clean your workspace when your task is complete
- Would you mind awfully, cleaning up your workspace? (and the meaning of "awfully" in this case is "very", as in would you mind a lot)

**Example 2**

- Do you think it would be a good idea to modify the program to do xyz?
- Could you please modify the program as per the jira task?
- I would be grateful if you could modify the program by end of day tomorrow
- Do you need any help in modifying the program per the user feedback?
- When do you think the xyz modification will be complete?
- Please could you raise the xyz modification to the top of your priority list
- The xyz change to the program is important, please you could you work on it as a priority?